# Insert statement - select within value error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to run something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
(RULE_ID, SYSTEM_KEY, FIELD, FIELD_VALUE, SOURCE_FIELD_VALUE_DESCRIPTION)
values ((SELECT TO_NUMBER(max(RULE_ID) + 1) as RULE_ID from TABLE_A),6,'CARS',22,'TOYOTA')
```

however, I keep getting an error:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [(SELECT
> CAST((CAST(TO_NUMBER(MAX(TABLE_A.RULE_ID), 18, 5) AS NUMBER(18,5))) +
> 1 AS NUMBER(38,0)) AS "RULE_ID" FROM DB.SCHEMA.TABLE_A AS TABLE_A)] in
> VALUES clause

I don't see any erorrs in my query though, do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it use simple `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
(RULE_ID, SYSTEM_KEY, FIELD, FIELD_VALUE, SOURCE_FIELD_VALUE_DESCRIPTION)
SELECT (SELECT TO_NUMBER(max(RULE_ID) + 1) as RULE_ID from TABLE_A),6,'CARS',22,'TOYOTA';
```

Second: `MAX(...) + 1` is not safe with concurrent queries. A much safer approach is usage of [SEQUENCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence) or [IDENTITY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#optional-parameters) column.

Answer (score 0):

The VALUES clause is intended for literal values, not an expression.

Just use...

```
INSERT INTO
  TABLE_A
    (RULE_ID, SYSTEM_KEY, FIELD, FIELD_VALUE, SOURCE_FIELD_VALUE_DESCRIPTION)
SELECT
  TO_NUMBER(max(RULE_ID)) + 1,6,'CARS',22,'TOYOTA'
FROM
  TABLE_A
```